# Misterious margin appearing in ul list

Tags: html, css

to me this is really weird, i have this menu:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.menu{text-align:right;}
            div.menu ul{
                list-style:none;
                display:inline;
            }
            div.menu li{
                position:relative;
                display:inline;
                background:#434343;
                padding:8px 12px;
                line-height: 32px;
                margin:0;
                border-left:1px #000 solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li> </li>
        <li></li>
        <li>Hi</li>
        <li>Hello </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i'm using the latest chrome and firefox 3.6 for testing

there are 6 li but only 5 are shown, a space inside the li causes it not to be rendered
if there's a text inside it causes a 4px space

"hi" has a space after, "hello " doesn't

adding anchors inside the li causes the same behaviour

```
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

has a space after

```
   <li><a href="#">Link</a> </li>
```

doesn't

adding 
       div.menu li a:after{content:" ";}
in the code would solve the problem apparently but if you look closely the elements will appear wider except the last one

any help?

thank you

Comment: So you are asking - why is there a gap between Hi and Hello? http://jsfiddle.net/8tScc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    div.menu{text-align:right;}
    div.menu ul{
        float:right;
...
    }
    div.menu li{
        float:left;
...
    }
```

Comment: that's really nice thanks 
but do you know a reason for what appeared to me as a weird behaviour on my code?

Comment: @mstrobilo the li size not set that causes problem if you use float:left; it fit the li size

Comment: @mgraph ok, nice floating right the inline ul to align right the menu, you've been really helpful, thanks

Comment: this is nothing to do with what is causing the problem.... please refer to my answer or answer by Mr Lister

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me:

[image: looks fine ^_^]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/hgde9/show/

Chrome About:

```
Google Chrome   18.0.1017.2 (Official Build 118867) dev-m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.19 (@105663)
JavaScript  V8 3.8.7.1
```

---

### Update:

Add:

```
float: right;
height: 32px;
```

To `div.menu li`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/hgde9/1/show/

Comment: that's not fine to me, 5/6 elements are displayed and there's a white space in the middle

Comment: @mstrobilo hmmm ddnt know that was what you were talking about... looking into it.

Comment: floating right the li elements will invert the position of the menu elements, see mgraph answer.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `display:inline`. Two inline elements next to each other have a space between them if there is wehitespace in the source. Or if there is a space inside one of the elements. Whitespace collapses, so the space in "Hello " is folded with the space after it and ends up inside the li, while there is no whitespace in the "Hi", only after.

Comment: Adding `display: inline-block` fixes the problem in Chrome, but causes IE to newline-break after each `li`.

Answer (score -1):

there is white space in the html, remove that and the gap will go! as in try this html

```
<ul><li></li><li> </li><li></li><li>Hi</li><li>Hello </li><li></li></ul>
```

and all will be revealed! (its nothing to do with CSS!)